# Como deshabiltar collapse en formulario hasta enviar

Tags: jquery, formularios, bootstrap-4

Tengo un código, está acá: https://jsfiddle.net/mca_mac/onmvkj5f/
Es un simple formulario asociado a un botón con el evento collapse:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mt-3 ml-4">
            <div class="col-8">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block my-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#multiCollapseExample1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">FORM</button>

                    <div class="form-group collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
                    <form action="">

                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name">
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your name</div>

                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" name="email" id="email">
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your email</div>

                        <label for="message">Message</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control"></textarea>

                        <label for="occupation">Occupation</label>
                        <select name="occupation" id="occupation" class="form-control">
                            <option value="student">Mexico</option>
                            <option value="executive">España</option>
                            <option value="other">Colombia</option>
                        </select>

                        <button class="btn btn-primary"  name="sendForm" id="sendForm" type="submit">Send</button>
                        <div class="txt"></div>

                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Para hacer la validación ocupé esto:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var enable = $('[data-toggle=collapse]').prop('enable',true);
    var disable = $('[data-toggle=collapse]').prop('disabled',true);
    $('#sendForm').on('click', function() {
        var fName = $("input[type=text][name=name]").val().length;
        var fEmail = $("input[type=text][name=email").val();
        var fTxt = [];

        valid = true;

        $("#name").removeClass("is-invalid");
        $("#email").removeClass("is-invalid");
        $('.txt').empty();

        if (fName < 2) {
            $("#name").addClass("is-invalid");
            valid = false;
        }

        if (fEmail.indexOf('@', 0) == -1 || fEmail.indexOf('.', 0) == -1) {
            $("#email").addClass("is-invalid");
            valid = false;
        }

        return valid;

    });
});
```

Necesito deshabilitar el evento collapse hasta validar correctamente el formulario (si no lo hago, durante cada validación el formulario se oculta).
Para eso ocupé esta función:

```
$('#multiCollapseExample1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    disable;
});
```

y necesito demorar el evento collapse durante el envío, para mostrale al usuario un mensaje de éxito en el envío, y asegurarme de que la información ha sido enviada.

```
$('#multiCollapseExample1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(".txt").push('Form send!');
    enable.delay(2000);
});
```

Lamentablemente no funciona el código y el formulario no se despliega. Alguien me podría ayudar?

Comment: ¿Para qué tienes esta línea `var disable = $('[data-toggle=collapse]').prop('disabled',true);`? Con ella no hay forma de desplegar el form.

Comment: Si puedo entender, lo que hace esa línea es deshabilitar(disabled) el efecto collapse `$('[data-toggle=collapse]')`, con lo que el formulario no se ocultaría

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como puedes hacerlo, está todo comentado para que se entienda.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   // No existe la propiedad “enable” que usabas. La vamos a reemplazar por “disabled”.
   /* No existe la propiedad “enable” que usabas. La vamos a reemplazar por “disabled”.*/
   
   $('#multiCollapseExample1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            $('[data-toggle=collapse]').prop('disabled',true);
    });
    /* Vamos a capturar el submit de nuestro form*/
    $("#myForm").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // vamos a evitar que lo envíe.
        
        /*
            resto del codigo...
            Las validaciones usadas son las basicas de HTML5.
            Por lo que con agregar "required a tu input lo puedes lograr facilmente.
            Pero si deseas hacer validaciones personalizadas las debes agregar aqui. 
            
        */
        
        //Validacion === true
        // entonces envio el form.
        
        $('[data-toggle=collapse]').prop('disabled',false);
        $('[data-toggle=collapse]').click();
        $(".txt").html(
        `
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
          Form send!
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
        </div>
        `);
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row mt-3 ml-4">
    <div class="col-8">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block my-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#multiCollapseExample1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">FORM</button>
      <div class="form-group collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
        <form action="#" id="myForm">

          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your name</div>

          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" name="email" id="email" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your email</div>

          <label for="message">Message</label>
          <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control"></textarea>

          <label for="occupation">Occupation</label>
          <select name="occupation" id="occupation" class="form-control">
            <option value="student">student</option>
            <option value="executive">executive</option>
            <option value="other">other</option>
          </select>

          <button class="btn btn-primary" name="sendForm" id="sendForm" type="submit">Send</button>
          

        </form>
      </div>
       <div class="txt"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Editado:** te dejo el jsfiddle que me dejaste en los comentarios editado y corregido. Estaba mal tu regex, por otro lado debías sacar el div `.text` de tu collapse sino no lo vas a ver, no habías declarado "valid" y estabas ejecutado el success fuera de tu evento submit.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mt-3 ml-4">
        <div class="col-8">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block my-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#multiCollapseExample1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">FORM</button>
            <div class="form-group collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
                <form action="" id="myForm">

                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name">
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your name</div>

                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" name="email" id="email">
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your email</div>

                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control"></textarea>

                    <label for="occupation">Occupation</label>
                    <select name="occupation" id="occupation" class="form-control">
                        <option value="student">Mexico</option>
                        <option value="executive">España</option>
                        <option value="other">Colombia</option>
                    </select>

                    <button class="btn btn-primary"  name="sendForm" id="sendForm" type="submit">Send</button>


                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="txt" role="alert"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#multiCollapseExample1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            $('[data-toggle=collapse]').prop('disabled',true);
        });
        $("#myForm").on("submit", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var nameVal = $("input[type=text][name=name]").val();
            var emailVal = $("input[type=text][name=email").val();
            var  valid = true;

        $("#name").removeClass("is-invalid");
        $("#email").removeClass("is-invalid");
        //$('.txt').empty();
        if ((nameVal).length < 2) {
            $("#name").addClass("is-invalid");
            valid = false;
        }
        if (
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/.test(emailVal)) {
            $("#email").addClass("is-invalid");
            valid = false;
        }


        if(valid){
        $('[data-toggle=collapse]').prop('disabled',false);
        $('[data-toggle=collapse]').click();
        $(".txt").addClass("alert alert-success");
        $(".txt").html('Form SEND!');
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Lo intenté acá: https://jsfiddle.net/mca_mac/jafL4rv1/ pero no realiza bien la validación de mail y la consola muestra este error `ReferenceError: valid is not defined`

Comment: @maumca te dejo corregido en la pregunta. Arriba te explico los errores que encontré. Saludos

Comment: Yo pensé que el success era equivalente a retornar "valid". Muchas gracias @Fran Islas, ahora funciona bien.